# Merge array of hashes by some keys and sum values of other keys

Tags: ruby

I have a array like

```
array = [
  {"point"=>6, "score"=>4, "team"=>"Challenger"},
  {"point"=>4, "score"=>2, "team"=>"INB"},
  {"point"=>2, "score"=>2, "team"=>"Super-11"},
  {"point"=>3, "score"=>7, "team"=>"INB"}
]
```

I want to merge hashes by "team" and sum the values of "point" and "score". Additionally want to insert an key "qualified" in each hash if point is greater than 5. So the final result will be:

```
result= [
      {"point"=>6, "score"=>4, "qualified"=> "yes", "team"=>"Challenger"},
      {"point"=>7, "score"=>9, "qualified"=> "yes", "team"=>"INB"},
      {"point"=>2, "score"=>2, "qualified"=> "no", "team"=>"Super-11"}
    ]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Hash#merge` can be called with a block to fine-tune how you want it to do it. Obviously not the only part of the question of what you need, but possibly get you started.

Answer (score 3):

One more possible solution :)

```
array.group_by { |item| item['team'] }.map do |_, items| 
  result = items.inject({}) { |hash, item| hash.merge(item) { |_, old, new| Integer(old) + new rescue old } }
  result.merge("qualified" => result['point'] > 5 ? "yes" : "no")
end
```

Comment: Yes, two lines less!

Comment: This adds also the `team` keys, in the OP's example he would get a team called `INBINB` - you need to specify which keys are to sum up.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = array.group_by{|i| i['team']}
               .map do |k,v|
                 points = v.map{|i| i['point']}.inject(0, :+)
                 score = v.map{|i| i['score']}.inject(0, :+)
                 {
                   'point' => points, 
                   'score' => score, 
                   'qualified' => points > 5 ? 'yes' : 'no',
                   'team' => k
                 }
               end
```

Answer (score 2):

Combination of `group_by` and `map` should help

```
result = 
    array.group_by {|item| item['team'] }
         .map do |team, items|
             total_points = items.map{|item| item['point']}.reduce(0, :+)
             total_score = items.map{|item| item['score']}.reduce(0, :+)
             qualified = points > 5
             {
                 'point' => total_points, 
                 'score' => total_score, 
                 'qualified' => qualified ,
                 'team' => team
             }
          end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative version. group_by is mandatory, I guess.
I used a temporary hash with keys as symbol to store data during iterations.

```
result = array.group_by { |hash| hash['team'] }.map do |team|
  tmp_hash = {point: 0, score: 0, team: team[0], qualified: 'no'}
  team[1].each { |h| tmp_hash[:point] += h['point'] ; tmp_hash[:score] += h['score'] }
  tmp_hash[:qualified] = 'yes' if tmp_hash[:point] > 5
  tmp_hash
end
```

this gives as result:

```
# => [
#      {:point=>6, :score=>4, :team=>"Challenger", :qualified=>"yes"},
#      {:point=>7, :score=>9, :team=>"INB", :qualified=>"yes"},
#      {:point=>2, :score=>2, :team=>"Super-11", :qualified=>"no"}
#    ]
```

Comment: `tmp_hash.merge(qualified: tmp_hash[:point] > 5 ? 'yes' : 'no')` - will allow you to avoid returning of `tmp_hash`

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After doing `group_by`, a simple `map` operation which takes the first element as the mapped value, sums up `point` and `score` within it and then merges the `qualified` condition into it is easy enough:

```
array
  .group_by { |h| h["team"] }
  .map do |_, a|
    ["point", "score"].each { |k| a.first[k] = a.sum { |h| h[k] } }
    a.first.merge({"qualified": a.first["score"] > 5 ? 'yes' : 'no'})
  end
```

Online demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/ExpertPeachpuffSysadmin)

Comment: might want to mention the damage this does to `array`

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you correct, but it does not change `array` - `group_by` returns a new hash which i am working on with `map`. (Also i am not using `map!`)

Comment: `a.first[k] =` modifies the first hash in the group which is not a copy. Take a look at `array` before and after your methodology runs

Comment: I guess i am rather out of touch after 4 years of not using ruby, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["team"]=>g.merge("qualified"=>g["score"] > 5 ? "yes" : "no")) do |_,o,n|
    { "point"    =>o["point"]+n["point"],
      "score"    =>o["score"]+n["score"],
      "team"     =>o["team"],
      "qualified"=>(o["score"]+n["score"]) > 5 ? "yes" : "no" }
  end
end.values
  #=> [{"point"=>6, "score"=>4, "team"=>"Challenger", "qualified"=>"no"},
  #    {"point"=>7, "score"=>9, "team"=>"INB", "qualified"=>"yes"},
  #    {"point"=>2, "score"=>2, "team"=>"Super-11", "qualified"=>"no"}]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys (here the value of `:id`) that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for the description of the three block variables (here `_`, `o` and `n`).

Note that the receiver of `values` (at the end) is

```
{"Challenger"=>{"point"=>6, "score"=>4, "team"=>"Challenger", "qualified"=>"no"},
 "INB"=>{"point"=>7, "score"=>9, "team"=>"INB", "qualified"=>"yes"},
 "Super-11"=>{"point"=>2, "score"=>2, "team"=>"Super-11", "qualified"=>"no"}}
```

One could alternatively make a separate pass at the end to add the key `"qualified'`:

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["team"]=>g) do |_,o,n|
    { "point"    =>o["point"]+n["point"],
      "score"    =>o["score"]+n["score"],
      "team"     =>o["team"] }
  end
end.values.
    map { |h| h.merge("qualified"=>(h["score"] > 5) ? "yes" : "no") }
```